# Doxygen: How to link to annotated source code?

Tags: c++, doxygen

I have a very simple example Main.cpp file for my library, and I have a tutorial page for it. The page looks something like this:

```
/**
 *  @page simpleexample Simple Example
 *
 *  This example shows basic use. It is in \ref simple_example/Main.cpp.
 *
 *  And this is the description of the example.
 */
```

Now what this does is it replaces the `simple_example/Main.cpp` reference by a link to that file **documentation**. I would like it to go **directly to the annotated source code**.

Is there a way to do it without entirely disabling the per-file documentation? I'd like to have it, but i don't like that people need to click the Main.cpp link and then also the `Go to the source code of this file.` link once inside. I don't care too much about how the links in the Files section behave, although I'd rather have them go to file documentation, as they do by default.

I don't want to include the source code inside the tutorial page using `\example` either, as it is already there in small parts which are explained individually.

Comment: [An RFE created](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/7945).

Answer (score 3):

I found in my old code that I once used `main.c_source` to reference the annotated source code (not the documentation!), but testing in now it doesn't work...

The best solution I have for you us a hack.  Use HTML to reference the actual .html file of the annotated source.

```
<A HREF=main_8c_source.html><B> main.c annotated source </B></A>
```

From my observations Doxygen follows a standard renaming scheme.  The "." is change to "_8" consistently, and "_source" is appended to reference the source code.   Capitals are consistently changed to lower-case and preceded with an underscore.  `MyFile.c` becomes `_my_file_8c`

You must also set `CREATE_SUBDIRS = NO`.  If `CREATE_SUBDIRS = YES` then you can't really be sure which sub-directory the file will be in.

Of course as a hack, you can never be sure if it'll work in the next release. You'll always have to be double checking if it still works.  Maybe suggest it to them as a Feature request...

Comment: No, this is not what i want, and I mentioned it explicitly. The reference you provide is linking to `\example` reference. I specifically said "I don't want to include the source code inside the tutorial page using `\example`". Thank you for taking your time to answer.

Comment: ah... yes, I think I understand, and done this before.  Use the /ref main_c_source or something like that.  Don't have time today anymore to edit, give me 'til tomorrow...  :)

Comment: What I suggested in my comment yesterday was trying to address exactly what you want, **"_source"**.  If I put it in code quotes I guess it would be more clear: `/ref main_c_source`.  yes, I know it doesn't work... but I hadn't sold it as the answer yet either, did I?

Comment: and SOURCE_BROWSER = YES in the config file

Comment: Nice, I haven't thought of that. But unfortunately the project is quite large and ever-growing, CREATE_SUBDIRS=YES is a must. I like the HTML hack though, haven't thought of that.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of redirecting your reader *anywhere* you could take a different approach and quote the example code in your tutorial automatically using `\include` or `\snippet`.

I agree that the two-step effect of `\ref` is a bit of a faff, but even having a single step to go look at the code separately from the tutorial text breaks the concentration of the reader.

Depending on the volume of code in your 'example' you could either have it inserted into the doxygen output in its entirety with `\include` or you could quote the key parts in your tutorial page using `\snippet`.  The latter has the advantage that you can do it in parts interspersed by your tutorial text.

Both these have the mixed blessing that the included sample is treated as *code*.  This means that the doxygen comments in the target file will be shown as code rather than as doxygen.  This might seem undesirable but it will help make it clear which is tutorial text and which is the example file.  (That said, I've only ever used `snippet` for just quoting real code samples in a tutorial page myself.)

Relevant Doxygen manual section [here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdinclude).

I note you're not wanting to use `\example`. My approach is slightly different (especially with `\snippet`), and doesn't create the 'Examples' page.  This may still not be what you want, but I offer it here in case it's useful for others anyway.

Comment: I'm already using snippets of the code throughout the example. I know how to do that. I just wanted to show the whole file. The only solution I could think of is to make another page and use `\example` there. But that somehow creates duplicate page to the "real" code listing. Thanks for your effort anyway.

Comment: I did start just writing a comment but it got a bit long, hence the 'answer'.  @theswine The only other thing that occurred to me (but I've not tried) is whether you could like to the function/class (if your example is just the one) with the `\ref` rather than to the file.

Comment: That would not solve the problem, \ref would again go to class documentation, not source. Same problem there. My file does not contain any class, just a couple of functions showing one of the uses of my library. There are all already covered as snippets, all I wanted is to provide readers with link to "see the big picture".

Answer (score 1):

I tried some of the possibilities and what worked for me was to create separate pages for the example code.

```
 /**
 *  @page simpleexample Simple Example
 *
 *  This example shows basic use. It is in \ref simple_example_main.
 *
 *  And this is the description of the example.
 *
 *  @page simple_example_main Main.cpp
 *
 *  \include simple_example/Main.cpp
 */
```

That would give you the output

> This example shows basic use. It is in **Main.cpp**

Whereas I found the direct insertion of code from the **\include** command rather useful, as it allows you to insert more than one source per page, and have some floating text between the code files.

In order to get (any) example to work, you need to set the example path, in the example above it would probably be something like

```
EXAMPLE_PATH           = simple_example
EXAMPLE_PATTERNS       = *
EXAMPLE_RECURSIVE      = YES
```